# Leave cmd windows open (called from batch script)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am launching 4 executables from a batch script:

```
@echo off
start ../../../../LD_Server.exe 12321 23432 11221 3
start LD_Client.exe 12321 pero
start LD_Client.exe 23432 tina
start LD_Client.exe 11221 sanja
```

This opens 4 cmd windows but after they do their work they all close. I want them to stay opened so I can read the output. How?

Comment: mine stay open though i don't have that or an exe to try on at the moment,  I just tried start dir, start cmd /k dir. but try  start cmd /k  ld_client.exe   <-- do they stay open then. contrast with cmd /c where they'd close. maybe yours close even with a /k.  i think and thought /k was default.

Comment: by the way, you can do start LD_Client.exe 12321 pero >c:\a.a  to redirect to a file then the next one  use >> to append i.e. start LD_Client.exe 23432 tina >>c:\a.a    But that doesn't directly answer your q. Try the cmd /k I mention see if that helps

Comment: Hm, weird. Maybe it really works differently with .exe's. Anyhow, it's resolved now, see the answer below. Also thanks for suggestions!

Comment: You clearly didn't try my suggestion of cmd /k ld_client. It may have worked. But even though it's fine for you now. For the sake of knowing what's going on, can you try start cmd LD_Client.EXE and see if that closes immediately? Then try start cmd /k LD_Client.EXE. And report back.

Comment: Se comment on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
start %COMSPEC% /k ../../../../LD_Server.exe 12321 23432 11221 3
start %COMSPEC% /k LD_Client.exe 12321 pero
start %COMSPEC% /k LD_Client.exe 23432 tina
start %COMSPEC% /k LD_Client.exe 11221 sanja
```

`%COMSPEC%` is an environment variable that points to your system's command interpreter (on Windows NT, `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`), and the `/k` switch prevents the specified command's window from closing after execution.

Comment: Can you explain what these commands do and why they work?

Comment: though worth noting that if you open a cmd prompt and do start dir, it opens a new cmd prompt runs dir -and does not close that new cmd prompt- so it looks like /k is the default. And it looks like %COMSPEC% might also be default considering that start dir works. Maybe it works differently with EXEs?

Comment: Works great, I just needed to copy the `LD_Server to the same directory where the batch script resides, otherwise I got *".." unrecognised program*.

Answer (score 1):

from a cmd window.

start dir <-- opens new cmd window and keeps it open. so it by default does start cmd /k dir.

start cmd  wget (equivalent to your exe) closes it, so seems to do start cmd /c wget.

start cmd /k wget (as in my suggestion four hours ago that you perhaps couldn't read or understand or bother trying) keeps it open. Similarly with your exe.

furthermore it's a pretty lame question 'cos if you just googled how to stop cmd window from closing, you'd see stranght away about cmd /k and cmd /c, And if you did cmd /? you'd see them. It's not like with linux where you have tons of switches and you have to read pages and pages to find what you want.

Comment: I tried with `start cmd LD_Client.exe 12321 pero` in batch script and that resulted in creating more and more cmd windows until my computer crashed. Have no intentions to experiment anymore ;)

Comment: @PrimožKralj I never said to try that. I said "try start cmd /k ld_client.exe "